# Amsmath error occurs

Tags: amsmath

I have error

> ! Missing } inserted.
>    
>                   }
>   l.9 { -1+2/[1+3\exp(-2|J|/k_BT)],&
>                                      $T

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}  \label{eq:Cd}
\tilde C(T)=
\begin{cases}
{ -1+2/[1+3\exp(-2|J|/k_BT)],& $T<T_e$;\cr\cr 0,& $T\ge T_e$.\cr}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

When i comment `\usepackage{amsmath}` there is no error. I can't understand how to fix it, without `\usepackage{amsmath}` commenting.

Comment: When I remove the brackets and the dollar signs, the document compiles with `amsmath`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use math inside math: `$T<T_e$`.
Take off those $$:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}  \label{eq:Cd}
\tilde C(T)=
\begin{cases}
    -1+2/[1+3\exp (-2|J|/k_BT)], & T<T_e \\ 0,& T\ge T_e.    \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: correct, the `$` signs are definitely not needed.  a couple more suggestions: this would work as well (and perhaps better) with `equation` instead of `eqnarray`, and the final `\\` isn't needed at the end of `cases` (it would leave a probably-unwanted blank line).